# Why was Kugo Ginjo kicked out of the Soul Society?

Tags: bleach

I remember that Kugo Ginjo used to be a Substitute Shinigami, but he got kicked out and lost his shinigami status. Why did this happen?

Comment: It may be my misunderstanding, but I think being "substitute" shinigami means that he was never really part of Soul Society.

Comment: @ytg See this question: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/8667/what-does-it-mean-that-ichigo-and-ginjo-are-substitute-shinigami/8668#8668 (I had some friends who also had issues with this concept)

Comment: so they are not part of Soul Society, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not that Kūgo Ginjō got kicked out. He left on his own accord after feeling betrayed by the shinigami.

> Some time ago, Kūgo became the first Substitute Shinigami and in recognition of that was given a Substitute Shinigami badge by Captain Jūshirō Ukitake. How he gained Shinigami powers is unknown, but according to Captain Suì-Fēng, he murdered many Shinigami in order to steal their power. At some point, Kūgo found out that his badge was a surveillance device used by Soul Society to observe him and limit his power. After that discovery, **Kūgo thought he had been betrayed and disappeared without a trace.** - [Bleach wiki](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/K%C5%ABgo_Ginj%C5%8D)