# During the Substitute Shinigami arc, it is mentioned that Ichigo and Ginjo are Substitute Shinigami. What does this mean?

Tags: bleach

During the Substitute Shinigami arc, it is covered that both Ichigo and Ginjo are Substitute Shinigami (Ginjo being and ex-Substitute Shinigami). How does one become a Substitute Shinigami, what does this title bring with it, and why is Ginjo no logger a holder of said title?

Comment: As you may have noticed, fixing your answer has helped regain votes, the same can be done for your question, one suggestion can be by referring to which episode or chapter “Substitute Shinigami” are mentioned. Since also you self answered maybe tailor your question to your answer ie. "Who are Substitute Shinigami and how are they found", this is already covered in your answer

Comment: @Memor-X I was able to change both the title and the body to better convey what I was trying to get at. Do you think that this works better?

Comment: The body is much better (you can still fit the part about your friends not understanding the term). the question title in my opinion is a bit long than what it needs to be, remember that in the question body can flesh out a short question title. you already mention in your question body about the arc and the characters so you probably don't need them in the title, maybe something along the lines of _What does it mean when someone becomes a "Substitute Shinigami"_. though that's just my opinion, some people may prefer the question title as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Bleach Wiki:

> A Substitute Shinigami (死神代行, shinigami daikō) is someone who became Shinigami by obtaining another Shinigami's power, or by going through a much harder and riskier process to transform him/herself into one.

Ginjo was the first Substitute Shinigami that was recognized as such by the Gotei 13. The origin of his powers is unknown but according to Captain Soi-Fong he murdered many shinigami to get his powers.

Ichigo, on the other hand, received his powers from Rukia Kuchiki when she gave him a portion of her power by the method of endowing her zanpakuto with said power and stabbing Ichigo with it, in order to protect his family.

> If a Substitute Shinigami appears, Soul Society gives that Shinigami a special badge which they use to monitor and restrict the Substitute. However, the Substitute is told that it is a license which is given to Substitutes that prove beneficial to Soul Society to allow them to do their work and identify them as a Substitute. The badge alerts the user if Hollows are nearby via an alarm sound which can only be heard by the owner and the item itself is only visible to other spiritually aware beings. The Badge can also allow the soul to leave the body.

Ichigo received his badge after he went to ***SPOILER*** invade the Seireitei to rescue Rukia from being murdered on account of her giving power to a Human. The Gotei 13 saw the sheer power Ichigo possessed and recognized him as a Substitute Shinigami so they make keep an eye on him and call on him in times in need (*Personal opinion* which preceded to be the spine of the rest of the series's plot).

Ginjo received his badge for a similar reason, so that the Gotei 13 could watch his actions (specifically so he would not murder more Shinigami to gain power) and to call on him in times of need.***SPOILER*** In time he realized the real purpose of the badge and feeling betrayed he disappeared from the Gotei 13's radar without a trace.

Source:[Bleach Wikia](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Shinigami)

Comment: it might be better if you edited your answer to be more in your own words rather than a direct copy and paste from the wiki and maybe expand on some of information like comparing how the badge works to the Soul Candy and Soul Pager or how someone obtains another Shinigami's power in the first place

Comment: @Memor-X Is that better?

Comment: i'd edited the question to be a bit better formatted in my oppinion, i don't know who Ginjo is but maybe add the reason why he recived his bade since you state why Ichigo got his (The Gotei 13 saw the sheer power Ichigo possessed and recognized him as a Substitute Shinigami, Ginjo got his powers though murdering other Shinigami so i can't really think why he would be viewed the same as Ichigo)

Comment: @Memor-X Ginjo is from the Substitute Shinigami arc which takes place after the Fake Karakura Town arc, and I added the info.